# Accessing localhost (xampp) from another computer over LAN network - how to?

Tags: apache, xampp, localhost, remote-debugging, httpd.conf

I have just set up a wi-fi network at home. I have all my files on my desktop computer (192.168.1.56) and want to access localhost over there from another computer (192.168.1.2).

On my desktop I can access localhost through the normal http://localhost. Apache is running on port 80 as usual.

What do I have to do to achieve this? There is documentation on the net but they either don't work or are too fragmented and confusing to understand.

I think I have to make changes to my apache's httpd.conf file and the hosts file. Any ideas as to what changes to make?

Comment: People finding this question might be interested in [How do I connect to this localhost from another computer on the same network?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9682262/562769).

Comment: Here is what i did and worked for me on windows 10:  go to cmd and type ipconfig, then find your ipv4 address and rename your website url to that ip eg: http://192.168.0.2/example. Then search  windows for "Allow an app through windows firewall" click on it then click change settings and make sure the http apache server is ticked. Hope it helps

Comment: I am having a site named app.sitename.com. Now i can access site in another pc in same network using IP address. How to access with subdomian. app.ipaddress.com  is not working. What i to do to add subdomain in remote pc?

Answer (score 137, accepted):

Localhost is just a name given for the loopback, eg its like referring to yourself as "me" ..

To view it from other computers, chances are you need only do http://192.168.1.56 or http://myPcsName if that doesnt work, there is a chance that there is a firewall running on your computer, or the httpd.conf is only listening on 127.0.0.1

Comment: httpd.conf:
Listen 80

if I need to make a change to that, what would you recommend?

Comment: That just says listen on port 80, chances are its already listening.
netstat -a , look for items on port 80, it will tell you which IP(s) its listening on

Comment: protocol:tcp, local address:0.0.0.0:80, foreign address:desktoppcname, state:listening

Comment: There you go, that means its listening for any request on port 80, not just localhost, so, if your PC was called vr3609, then http to it should take you to your website.

Comment: except I get a "this website is temporarily down or moved to another location" message when I try to do that

Comment: if you http to the ip address of your server from the server, does it work? if so, its suggesting theres a firewall on the server blocking other machines getting to it.

Comment: bingo. when i use http://192.168.1.56 on desktop pc, i am able to see the site. so I am guessing I have a firewall problem. how do I fix this?

Comment: Ok, 192.168.1.56, thats the one with the website on right? You need to look at the config of it. What OS does it run? What firewall software is on it will vary with that. You need to find out what firewall software is on it, and then work out how to add port 80 to it to let other machines in. If its windows, chances are its part of your antivirus software, or, could even be the microsoft one.  If its linux chances are its ipchains but, its a whole new area of question.

Comment: its a windows vista pc. running windows firewall.

Comment: aha. got it working. that was the main issue. allowed port 80 on my subnet. thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I dont have vista, but on windows 7 under control panel, theres a windows firewall option, under there advanced you could go add port 80.

Comment: I have a MacOs, i installed xampp and started Apache and Mysql, imagine my ip is 192.168.64.2 (this is what xampp shows) then when i enter this ip on my mobile browser it wont open. What could be the problem ? ifconfig shows my ip as 192.168.0.102

Comment: Well, you likely have 2 ip addresses, depending on so many things.  Look at netstat and see what ip and port it is listening on.

Comment: Is it possible to access 192.168.1.5/project by using the hostname of the desktop with up 192.168.1.56 as pc_test/project if the host name is pc_test.

Comment: If dns has it registered as that name yes

Comment: you wrote: To view it from other computers, chances are you need only do http://192.168.1.56 or http://myPcsName.
It is only true if other computers on same network.

Comment: 192 .168 is going to be a local network - it maybe a multifaceted network, but given both computers were only a few IP apart this is unlikely @NavinGiri

Answer (score 68):

it's very easy

1. Go to Your XAMPP Control panel
2. Click on apache > config > Apache (httpd.conf)  [image]
3. Search for **Listen 80** and replace with **Listen 8080**
4. After that check your local ip using **ipconfig** command (cmd console)
5. Search for **ServerName localhost:80** and replace with **your local ip:8080** (ex.192.168.1.156:8080)
6. After that open apache > config > Apache (httpd-xampp.conf) [image]
7. Search for

   ````
      <Directory "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin">
          AllowOverride AuthConfig
          **Require local**   Replace with   **Require all granted**
          ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
      </Directory>```
   ````
8. Go to xampp > config > click on service and port setting and change apache port **8080**
9. restart xampp
10. then hit your IP:8080 (ex.192.168.1.156:8080) from another computer

Comment: if instead of all graned... jsut an static IP. how it would be?

Comment: not working. in my pc it's work fine but not working from another pc .

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I'm getting a certificate error: server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

Comment: Hi @Rahul Shewale this works for IP but how to make it work for domain/subdomain? example `portal.localhost`?

Comment: Will this make my PC more vulnerable to attacks (outside LAN) ?

Comment: You shouldn't have to change the HTTP port. A web server on a LAN should be able to serve html pages on the default port 80.

Answer (score 58):

Thanks for a detailed explanation.

Just to Elaborate, in Windows, Go to Control Panel -> Firewall, in exceptions "add http and port 80". Then in Services check mark "http (web server port 80)" and "https (web server port 443)" **ONLY** if you need https to work also. Ok, OK, Close

Then go to any computer on network and type http://computer-name (where you change the firewall and has the xampp running on it) in your web browser and happy days :)

Comment: I went to Control Panel > Windows Firewall > Allow an app through Windows Firewall > Allow another app > Browse to: XAMPP/apache/bin/httpd.exe and allowed it. It is working now!

Comment: Thank you. Working fine.

Comment: To add the Windows Firewall exception, you can visit this to learn how: https://www.tomshardware.com/news/how-to-open-firewall-ports-in-windows-10,36451.html

Comment: @shasikanth you should add as an answer. Worked well for me.

Answer (score 25):

These are the steps to follow when you want your PHP application to be installed on a LAN server (not on web)

1. Get the internal IP or Static IP of the server (Ex: 192.168.1.193)
2. Open XAMPP>apache>conf>httpd.conf file in notepad
3. Search for Listen 80
4. Above line would read like- #Listen 0.0.0.0:80 / 12.34.56.78:80
5. Change the IP address and replace it with the static IP
6. Save the httpd.conf file ensuring that the server is pointed to #Listen 192.168.1.193:80
7. In the application root config.php (db connection) replace localhost with IP address of the server

Note:
If firewall is installed, ensure that you add the http port 80 and 8080 to exceptions and allow to listen.
Go to Control Panel>Windows Firewall>Allow a program to communicate through windows firewall>Add another program
Name: http
Port: 80
Add one more as http - 8080

If IIS (Microsoft .Net Application Internet Information Server) is installed with any Microsoft .Net application already on server, then it would have already occupied 80 port. In that case change the #Listen 192.168.1.193:80 to #Listen 192.168.1.193:8080

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: This solved it for me. Great stuff! I always had deleted the `#` in front of the local IP address and it was not working, when I included the comment hash `#` it worked out of the box without restarting the guest VM, just the XAMPP Apache service and bang it is there. Nice one. Now how do I get it to link to my assigned VirutalHosts on the Host machine?

Comment: To access the assigned VirtualHosts on the Host machine from the guest I simply had to enter the Host's IP and the name of the VirtualHost server(s) in the Guest's HOSTS file. Done. Anyone know how to pick up traffic from the Guest's browser to the Hosts Apache server with Fiddler. Work on the Host but not getting traffic from guest.

Comment: Hi, what about a range of IP addresses for e.g. 192.168.1-100. How to set that?

Answer (score 7):

Sometimes your firewall can be the problem. Make sure you've disabled your antivirus firewall monitoring. It worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

If someone is still finding it hard, this simple thing worked for me:

1. On you main system let's say Hosting PC...
   Go to Control Panel > Windows Defender Firewall > Allow an app or feature through Windows Defender Firewall > Change settings > Find "Apache HTTP Server" > Check both the check-boxes (under Private & Public).
   [See Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8Dc9.png)

   - In my case there were two "Apache HTTP Server" entries, so I checked both the check-boxes for both entries.
2. On any another system connected over a same network...
   Open browser > type: your hosting pc's IP adress followed by your project name in the url bar. Example: 192.168.72.111/example.com/

Hope it helps!
Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

This should be all you need for a basic setup

This kind of configuration doesn't break phpMyAdmin on localhost

A static IP is recommended on the device running the server

This example uses the 192.168.1.x IP. Your network configuration might use a different IP

In the httpd.conf in Apache you should have:

```
# Listen: Allows you to bind Apache to specific IP addresses and/or
# ports, instead of the default. See also the <VirtualHost>
# directive.
#
# Change this to Listen on specific IP addresses as shown below to 
# prevent Apache from glomming onto all bound IP addresses.
#
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen 80
```

I would leave blank the name so it gets the defaults:

```
# ServerName gives the name and port that the server uses to identify itself.
# This can often be determined automatically, but we recommend you specify
# it explicitly to prevent problems during startup.
#
# If your host doesn't have a registered DNS name, enter its IP address here.
#
```

Allow the guest machines and yourself. As a security caution, you might avoid *Allow from all* but instead use specific guest IP for example *Allow from 192.168.1.xxx* where xxx is the guest machine IP. In this case you might need to consider static IPs on guest machines also

```
# Controls who can get stuff from this server.
#
#    Require all granted
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
     Order Deny,Allow
#     Deny from all
     Allow from all 
     Allow from 127.0.0.1
     Allow from ::1
     Allow from localhost
     Allow from 192.168.1.*YOURguestIP*
     Allow from 192.168.1.*YOURselfIP*
</Directory>
```

*Restart all services* and *Put Online* from the tray icon

Answer (score 5):

Go to xampp-control in the Taskbar

```
xampp-control -> Apache --> Config --> httpd.conf
```

Notepad will open with the config file

Search for

> Listen 80

One line above it, there will be something like this: 12.34.56:80

Change it

```
12.34.56:80 --> <your_ip_address eg:192.168.1.5>:80
```

Restart the apache service and check it,
Hopefully it should work...

Comment: doesn't work for me. sorry. also this is a duplicate answer

Answer (score 4):

If you are using XAMPP 1.8.3
Navigate to file httpd-xampp.conf and search for 
"
      #
      # New XAMPP security concept
      #
        
         server-status | server-info))">

```
     Require local
     ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
     </LocationMatch>
```

"

Cut this code and save it somewhere for later use i.e restoring this feature( remember removing this code makes your computer vulnerable). Save changes on httpd-xampp.conf, restart services on XAMPP and that's it.

Comment: For XAMPP Version 7  the "Require local" is located in the file apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

Answer (score 4):

## Access localhost from Remote Device

**Prerequisite**: Your website is currently on `http://localhost:8081/` with a tool like [**live-server**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/live-server)

#### a) Publish on *Same* Network

Within the same network, you can access your machine with your current ip address or hostname. You can find the ip address running `ipconfig | grep IPv4` or the hostname by sending a `ping -a` to that ip.

```
http://192.128.1.18:80/
http://hostname:80/
```

**Note**: For best results, use port 80, connect on a private network, and check your firewall settings.

#### b) Publish on *Any* Network *(easier)*

1. **Opt 1** - You can use [**ngrok**](https://ngrok.com/) to provide port forwarding over ngrok's public facing ports

   [Download ngrok](https://ngrok.com/download) and run the following command:

   ```
   $ ./ngrok http 8081
   ```

   [image]
2. **Opt 2** - You can use [**localhost.run**](http://localhost.run/) to create a ssh tunnel with the following command:

   ```
   ssh -R 80:localhost:8081 kylemit@ssh.localhost.run
   ```

   [image]

---

## Access Remote Device from Local Dev Tools

To connect your browser dev tools with a connected device, follow the instructions at [Get Started with Remote Debugging Android Devices](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/)

1. On your phone, enable Developer Options & USB Debugging
2. Plug your phone into your computer via USB and set the protocol (not File / Media Transfer)
3. Open Dev Tools > More Tools > Remote Debugging (try here if [Device Not Detected](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21925992/1366033))

   [image]
4. Find your site and Click Inspect which will open up a new inspector window

   [image]

---

#### Further Reading:

- [How do I connect to this localhost from another computer on the same network?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9682262/1366033)
- [Access to a site on localhost from remote](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11364406/1366033)
- [How to debug web sites on mobile devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5794984/1366033)

Answer (score 3):

This tool saved me a lot, since I have no Admin permission on my machine and already had nodejs installed. For some reason the configuration on my network does not give me access to other machines just pointing the IP on the browser.

```
# Using a local.dev vhost
$ browser-sync start --proxy

# Using a local.dev vhost with PORT
$ browser-sync start --proxy local.dev:8001

# Using a localhost address
$ browser-sync start --proxy localhost:8001

# Using a localhost address in a sub-dir
$ browser-sync start --proxy localhost:8080/site1
```

http://www.browsersync.io/docs/command-line/

Answer (score 2):

After ensuring you've got the appache configs set up as described in the other answers on this page, you may need to also open TCP ports through your firewall as described here:

https://superuser.com/questions/569227/xampp-is-not-accessible-from-other-computer-through-lan-when-firewall-is-enable

Answer (score 2):

Here is what i did and worked for me on **windows 10**:
1) Hit **windows + r** and type **cmd** . In the command prompt type **ipconfig**
2) find your **ipv4** address and rename your website url to that ip eg: http://192.168.0.2/example. 
3) Now make sure your **firewall** has access to **Apache HTTP Server**. Search  windows for "**Allow an app through windows firewall**" click on it then on the top right click **change settings**  and make sure the Apache HTTP Server has one tick on the left and one on the private or public. Hope it helps

Now you can access the website from other PCs in the lan

Answer (score 1):

If you are connected to Wi-Fi network, then it is much simpler. Just find the Ip in which you have connected to the Wi-Fi. Eg:

> your-ip is  "10.10.55.67".

Then start the xampp server in your machine.

Then in anyother computer connected to the same Wi-Fi n/w, type

`http://your-ip`

Eg:`http://10.10.55.67`

Comment: isn't this the question itself?

Answer (score 1):

Just try:

```
http://ipaddressofpcwhichhasdatabase:portnumber(80 by default)/filename.extension
```

Answer (score 0):

First you go to Command Prompt and type

`Notepad C:/windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts`

then add your ip adress below then the url of your site.

Second you go to Command Prompt and type 
`notepad c:/xampp/bin/apache/apache2.4.18/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`

then add this below

```
documentroot "Directory of your site"
Allow from all
Require all granted
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<Files ".ht*">
 Require all denied
</Files>

 replace to

<Files ".ht*">
 Require local
</Files>
```

Comment: <Files ".ht*">
 Require local
   #Require all denied
</Files>

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

First Go To Network and Sharing center of your windows machine.and Just follow some steps to get your IPv4 address.
[image: Just See The Image Illustration]

**Put the IPv4 adress on another computer browser. example,http//192.168.0.102**

**Note**

- Turn Of Your Windows Firewall (if does not work,otherwise its optional)

Answer (score 0):

Replace 
`Require Local` with `Require all granted` in `xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-xampp.conf` file.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue. I was using XAMPP in a virtual machine which was having network setting as "NAT". I changed it to "Bridged" and the problem got solved.

Answer (score 0):

Host in  local IP,

Open CMD : ipconfig

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : xx.xxx.xx.xxx

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that windows 10 home edition does not support hosting website.

windows 10 professional does support hosting website, so it works once add the windows machines ip address to httpd.conf file after listen 80, the ip address for the local hosting windows machine can be found by ipconfig in cmd windows.

Listen 80

Listen 192.168.0.197:80

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: There's no real reason I could see why this would not work on Windows 10 Home, could you elaborate on that?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to access Apache running on localhost from another computer is using https://pinggy.io . Just run the following command:

```
ssh -p 443 -R0:localhost:80 a.pinggy.io
```

It will give you a public URL.

Answer (score -1):

So I was trying to solve a similar problem with connecting to a totally different server on my own LAN so that when power is interrupted and then restored that my server comes back online and other systems can still have connectivity with automation. However, my problem was DHCP giving my server a diff IP on occasion. This thread answered my problem with the NAMESERVER that windows have natively. I was connecting directly to my servers IP add http://192.168.1.5 through a batch file to initialize the connection but when power problems happen it would not connect.  I changed the .bat file to point at http://DESKTOP-actualnamewhereserver:port and done. Problem solved.  IF I don't change my computers names then when DHCP hands DESKTOP-actualnamewhereserver a new IP address it will still identify as its own name on the LAN and therefore be able to accept the connection regardless of it's IP Address.  Simply give the other people on your wireless LAN the name of your pc hosting the Apache server and lets say its name is DESKTOP-DOUGHFACTORYHUT they will type http://DOUGHFACTORYHUT:80 or whatever port number your apache config is set to host at like LOCALHOST:80 which essentially are the same thing attached to your local Dynamic IP address assigned by DHCP or STATIC IP you have set to the server.

Answer (score -2):

I am Fully agree With BugFinder.

In simple Words, just put ip address *192.168.1.56* in your browser running on *192.168.1.2*!

if it does not work then there are following possible reasons for that :

1. Network Connectivity Issue :

   - First of all Check your network Connectivity using *ping 192.168.1.56* command in command prompt/terminal on 192.168.1.2 computer.
2. Firewall Problem : 
   Your windows firewall setting do not have allowing rule for XAMPP(apache).
   (Most probable problem)

   - (solution)
     go to advanced firewall settings and add inbound and outbound rules for Apache executable file.
3. Apache Configuration problem. : 
   Your apache is configured to listen only local requests.

   - (Solution)
     you can it by opening httpd.conf file and replace 
     *Listen 127.0.0.1:80* to *Listen 80* or *Listen *:80*
4. Port Conflict with other Servers(IIS etc.)

   - (Solution) Turn off apache server and then open local host in browser. if any response is obtained then turnoff that server then start Apache.

if all above does not work then probably there is some configuration problem on your apache server.try to find it out otherwise just reinstall it and transfer all php files(htdocs) to new installation of XAMPP/WAMP.

Comment: First of all, this post is 5 years old, so this answer probably won't be helpful to the OP. Second, you can use [Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to improve the formatting of your answer to make it more readable and easier to follow. Trust me in that it's a nice thing to know. :-)

Answer (score -3):

To Run **Nodejs** Server over Network

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000; 
const server = http.createServer( 
server.listen(port, '0.0.0.0', ()  => console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`)
));
```

run http://yournetworkipaddress:3000 to access your application over local area network (LAN)

Steps to find your network ip.

**MacOS**

1. Go to System Preferences > Network
2. Check network IP address under the connected.