# Cannot Send Console Commands To iOS Device From Safari Web Inspector

Tags: javascript, ios, macos, safari, safari-web-inspector

The Sarari Web Inspector Guide [says](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/Console/Console.html):

> Use the console as a tool to modify your web content via interactive commands

It then goes on to list some example commands including `console.log(object)`.

However, when I try any command at all and hit enter, nothing happens.

[image: Screenshot]

What am I missing? Why can't I send my console commands via the enter key?

Comment: ever have any joy with this? have the same problem..

Comment: @Haroldo Yeah, it just started working after a while. I don't think I really did anything "different". Sorry that probably doesn't sound very helpful! Maybe try rebooting everything...

Comment: Thanks @Joncom, appreciate the response - fingers crossed!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to debug web sites on mobile devices?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794984/how-to-debug-web-sites-on-mobile-devices)

Comment: No @PaulSweatte, because the question you linked asks "how do people debug on mobile in general". This question pre-supposes that knowledge, and a specific platform (iOS), and then asks why a specific feature on the platform is not behaving as expected.

Answer (score 4):

TLDR: Install Safari Technology Preview https://developer.apple.com/safari/download/

My console stopped working after upgrading to:

macOS: Big Sur 11.4 (20F71)
Safari: 14.1.1 (16611.2.7.1.4)
iPhone iOS: 14.5

Spent a few hours trying to fix this, resetting, rebooting, reinstalling, etc. until I found this comment suggesting to try Safari Technology Preview. My regular Safari still doesn't work, but Safari Technology Preview (Release 125 (Safari 14.2, WebKit 16612.1.15.1.12)) works like a charm.

[Safari web inspector is only showing Sources, Console and Audit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60963057/safari-web-inspector-is-only-showing-sources-console-and-audit#comment112035489_60963057)

Safari Technology Preview installs in parallel to the regular Safari, you can use it just for development. Find it here https://developer.apple.com/safari/download/

Comment: This worked like a charm! Had the same problem, installed the Safari Technology Preview and it showed the multiple tabs and worked. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that Safari on your mobile device is up and running all the time.

I mean the phone doesn't enter sleep mode or anything like that.

It is best to perform some action on the mobile device, to ensure it is awake, then immediately go to the console on your MAC it should work.