# Safari web inspector is only showing Sources, Console and Audit

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, web-inspector, safari-web-inspector

After upgrading to Xcode 11.3.1, I am having problems using Safari web inspector with the iOS 12.1 simulator. Every time that I run an app inside of an iOS 12.1 simulator device, it will show up in the Safari debug menu and allow me to connect to it, but the only tabs I will see are Sources, Console and Audit.

Here is a screenshot of the inspector attached to an instance of the Safari browser inside of the simulator.

[image]

Is there any way to resolve this?

Environment:

- MacOS 10.14.6 (18G95)
- Xcode 11.3.1
- Safari 13.1 (14609.1.20.111.8)
- Simulator Version 11.3.1 (SimulatorApp-912.5.1 SimulatorKit-570.3
  CoreSimulator-681.17.2)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow :) Do you have some reason to not upgrade the iPad to iPadOS 13.x? Can you try using a device running iOS/iPadOS 13.x and see if the issue persists?

Comment: It work fine with devices running iOS 13.x

Comment: What about those who wish to support iOs < 13 ?

Comment: Same problem here. Is there at least any way to downgrade Xcode/Safari to resolve the issue?

Comment: The issue exists for iOS version <= 12.0 But not for iOS version >= 12.4. Just test the Safari using simulators with these two versions.

Comment: I am getting addicted to this poor user experience with so many breaks after every macOS upgrade. This is what Apple really means: get this simple update and I will break all previously working things for you.

Comment: I hit the same issue. I upgraded XCode and macOS ( to get Safari updates ).  Neither helped. Once I updated to the latest Safari Technology Preview from https://developer.apple.com/safari/download/ it all worked and I could see `Network`, `Storage` tabs.

Comment: @rustyMagnet I just tried Safari Technology Preview 113, it didn't work for me.  It can't even find an "Inspectible Application" for my iOS9 device.  (I am on most recent High Sierra)

Comment: @Lindsay-Needs-Sleep have you tried iOS 11 or above ?  There are a lot of things with WKWebView are not supported in iOS 9.

Comment: @rustyMagnet Yep, I have.  It works fine for my iOS 12.4.8 and iOS 13.7 devices.  It doesn't work with iOS 9.3.5 or iOS 10.3.4.  The problem is that a lot of our users can't afford new devices, so we want to continue supporting the older ones, but it has become incredibly difficult to debug and fix issues that only arise on 9+10 now. :(

Comment: I have the same issue,
iOs ipad 14.4.2
Mac os big sur 11.4
XCode 12.5
Safari 14.1.1 I tried to untrust my ipad, and renew.
I tried with another devices.
I tried with chrome dev tools but I'm not able to debug correctly because it can't upload .map. So it isn't usable. Nothing works. Maybe it's after an update because the last week, it worked.

Answer (score 21):

Web Inspector engineer here...

This appears to be a bug in Web Inspector, and we are investigating the issue. Does it happen if you use a recent Safari Technology Preview to inspect your older iOS devices?

In addition to asking on SO.. it is strongly recommended to report bugs pertaining to developer tools at https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/ so that you get notifications about followup questions and when a fix has been shipped.

EDIT(May 14): The issue is fixed in our tree and the fix should be included in Safari Technology Preview 107 and the next major Safari release. Stay tuned for release notes.

Comment: Yes, also happens with Safari Technology Preview. Is there a way to report the bug that doesn't require signing up for an Apple Program? Honestly, I don't feel like installing an app just to report a bug..

Comment: Is there an entry for this now by any chance?

Comment: I mean.. if you are developing on an Apple platform, you probably have an Apple ID already. What's the big deal about logging in? If you don't sign up, how are we going to contact you? Most bugs have at least one round of feedback / followup / questions.

StackOverflow is a crappy bug reporting system. Please use the real bug reporting system, so that we can address these issues in a timely manner.

Comment: just tried the technology preview 107 and it says enable web inspector on device, even though i have retried many times to re-enable it.

Comment: @hiradyazdan This sounds like a separate issue, please file a bug as outlined in my OP.

Comment: iPadOS 13.5.1 & macOS 10.15.4 having the exact same problem

Comment: @Pmpr those releases are affected, the fix will be included in macOS 10.16 and iOS 14.

Comment: @BrianBurg Could you include the link to this bug report?  (I have downloaded safari technology preview 108, and now it just doesn't even show any debuggable contexts for iOS 9.3.5, 10.3.4.  Works for 12.4.7, 13.5.1.  I will file a separate report, but I would like to read the original.)

Comment: @BrianBurg nvm, I see you can't share feedback reports. =/

Comment: So it looks like the problem is actually worse in Safari Technology Preview 107 and 108. 
For 107 and 108 Safari Technology Preview doesn't even appear to detect the webview for older iOS devices (< 12.x.x).

Comment: @Lindsay-Needs-Sleep Safary Technology Preview 108 worked for me using iOS Simulator 11.0.1.

Comment: "wait until iOS14 / MacOS 10.16" is not an acceptable answer. How the heck are we supposed to fix issues until that point?

Comment: @Elise Thanks!  I only had devices with iOS 10 and 9, (so I guess it is broken only for less than 11).

Comment: Yes it looks like the Web Inspector is completely broken for iOS 10!

Comment: I guess apple has given up on us?  Maybe if enough of report issues to  https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/  they will do something about it? T.T  Currently, it says this on my issue: "Recent Similar Reports:Less than 10".   **Please report the issue!**  Feel free to use a title like: "Can't debug webview for iOS < 11"

Comment: Hi folks, sorry for the lack of clarity.

I realize some folks still use iOS 9 and earlier. The WebKit project has no way to run automation against simulators and devices running those older releases, given the current testing infrastructure.

For remote inspection, iOS 10.3.4 is the minimum version supported by Safari 14. In general, Web Inspector's backwards compatibility matches the oldest Simulator runtime that Xcode supports in its most recent release.

If you are unable to inspect a device or simulator running iOS 10.3.4, please file a report at feedbackassistant.apple.com.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I just tried Safari Technology Preview 113 (14.0.1), and it still doesn't work with my iOS 10.3.4 device.  I submitted new feedback to the feedback assistant.

Comment: The latest iOS 10 simulator I can find in the simulator download list is 10.3.1. Does this mean it's impossible to debug iOS 10 without a real device that hasn't been upgraded?

Comment: Using the the latest Safari Tech Preview (113) and iOS 10.3.1 Simulator the tab eventually showed up in the Develop menu and Inspector is working as normal. Unsure what triggered it.

Comment: This issue is back now since I upgraded to Big Sure 11.4. Even the tabs that are visible are unusable. I hope Apple fixes that soon, as it makes remote debugging of iPhone web views impossible.

Comment: Big Sur 11.4 broke it again!

Comment: STP Release 125 (Safari 14.2, WebKit 16612.1.15.1.12) works for me on Big Sur 11.4

Comment: Can confirm that STP release 125 on Big Sur 11.4 does indeed work as per @helman

Comment: I can report that the Elements inspector reappered for me on Safari Technology Preview (but not on regular Safari) after upgrading to MacOS 11.4.

Comment: Same for me, working on tech preview Safari

Comment: works with Safari Tech Preview release 125 + Big Sur 11.4 + IOS 14.6

Comment: SFT readds the missing panels, but they have no content, just blank until I closed and reopened my app. Just FYI if anyone has that issue.

Comment: If it connects but Web Inspector immediately crashes, try completely restarting your device. Surprisingly worked for me. STP 127 + OSX 11.4 + iOS 14.6.

Comment: Also closing all apps on the device kept it from crashing.

Answer (score 20):

I don't yet want to update my macOS from High Sierra, but I still run into this bug (even on a clean installed test system).

Elsewhere it was suggested to use Safari Technology Preview - but now it's only for Catalina an Big Slur.

Fortunately you can still download older versions using Archive.org (bless their hearts).
This is the latest I found for High Sierra (Release 80, Posted: April 12, 2019):

https://web.archive.org/web/20190420021102/https://developer.apple.com/safari/download/

I guess you can find a later one for Mojave too.

---

### Update June 2021

For **macOS Big Sur 11.4**, you can <kbd>[download STP 125](https://web.archive.org/web/20210527101720/https://secure-appldnld.apple.com/STP/071-45899-20210526-3fe7359c-0f20-4850-b6ec-da9b197119c2/SafariTechnologyPreview.dmg)</kbd>.

Comment: I wish I could upvote more. :( You are a real life saver.

Comment: @Sanoop: I know, I saved my own one too with this trick. :) Anyway, it's nice from Apple for breaking High Sierra's Safari at the very last minute…

Comment: On Catalina, I tried technology preview 108, 107, 104,103,102,101, 98, 96.  None worked. :(  Guess I need to figure out how to go back to high sierra....

Comment: @Lindsay-Needs-Sleep: That sucks. Going forward doesn't help? https://www.macrumors.com/2020/09/09/apple-releases-safari-technology-preview-113/

Comment: I just tried Technology Preview 113, for my iPhone5 (10.3.4) and iPad3 (9.3.5), it shows "No Inspectible Applications" under the "Develop" menu.  (Regular Safari 13.1.2 at least finds the inspecitble application, but matches the behavior posted in the original issue.)  Both the technology preview and regular safari work with my iOS 13 device.

Comment: @Lindsay-Needs-Sleep: I use the iOS Simulator on High Sierra, and Safari TP 80 can connect to the iOS 12 but not to the iOS8 device (though the Web Inspector setting is enabled on iOS8Safari and iOS12Safari has no such setting). -- Edit: actually it can, maybe I messed with a simulator device.

Comment: Brilliant Biziclop... your use of wayback here salvages Apple for having this mission-critical dev bug, and then retracting the ability to download Safari Technology Preview on Big Sure (it is now unavailable as of this post). Your link to Wayback got me the original file and resolved this. Thank you!!!

Comment: @SeanHalls: Hi, you're welcome. It's worrying how popular is my answer. Unfortunately  only makes one type of software: that's already abandoned at the day of its release. :( And thanks to Zingi's edit with the new link.

Comment: I got same issue with Safari on Big sur 11.4. Using Safari Technology Preview solved the issue!

Answer (score 2):

(This is answer is less of a fix, and more of a superior alternative I wish I had discovered much sooner.)

You can just **debug iOS WebView** with **Chrome Dev Tools** instead of Safari!!

**Windows**
You can follow [this guide](https://washamdev.com/debug-a-website-in-ios-safari-on-windows/) to debug iOS webview on Windows with Chrome DevTools.  (Tested and works with iOS 9 and iOS 14 so far!!)  Edit: not working with iOS 9 today.... not sure what changed...

**Linux / Mac**
I believe you can *basically* follow [the windows guide](https://washamdev.com/debug-a-website-in-ios-safari-on-windows/) above for linux and Mac as well.  (*Comments confirming/denying welcome!*)

**Troubleshooting any part of the guide**
For any part of the guide that doesn't work (because out of date or linux/Mac), you can follow the instructions that are included directly with the tools that make this possible:

- [remotedebug-ios-webkit-adapter](https://github.com/RemoteDebug/remotedebug-ios-webkit-adapter)
- [ios-webkit-debug-proxy](https://github.com/google/ios-webkit-debug-proxy) (used by remotedebug-ios-webkit-adapter)

Comment: I tried going down this road but currently there is a bug showing a blank screen in devtools at the time of this comment. So... this is no dice. Use Biziclop's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try this older version [Safari Technology Preview](https://macupdate.com/app/mac/56677/safari-technology-preview), works for me on BigSur.

Comment: This is what you need to do, but at the time of this comment, Apple has removed the .dmg for BigSur's Safari Tech Preview. Use Biziclop's answer to grab it.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue after updating safari and MacOs to BigSur, for now we can use [Safari Technology preview](https://developer.apple.com/safari/download/) everything works fine.

Comment: that's the only solution that worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue with my iPad (iOS version: 11.x).

I resolved the issue by using another iPad (version: 13.3.1).

I think it doesn't support older version of web browser (Safari).

Answer (score -6):

You can actually right-click on the tabs to enable/disable certain tabs. After updating some of my tabs were also gone, this is how you restore them.

[image]

Comment: Yes, the problem @starmoon is having is that Safari 13.1 is failing to inspect iOS devices & simulators earlier than iOS 13. If you start the inspector with one of those devices/simulators, you can see `Audit Warning: "data-custom" is too new to run on this inspected page` in the Audit tab.

Comment: Well okay, I didn't got that from his question (still don't actually). My bad.

Comment: Although this answer didn't solve the Safari Technology Preview bug it did show me neat shortcut. Upvote from me.