# Console not logging in web inspector

Tags: testing, safari, web-inspector, safari-web-inspector, manual-testing

I am testing on Safari on an iPhone 5c and I use the Web Inspector to view the console logs. It hasn't been showing any logs as of lately, knowing that other iOS devices are working with the same desktop. Usually when I hook up the device and open the web inspector, logs start appearing but now it is blank, won't even accept any command lines.

[That's what the inspector looks like when opening it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6mbq.png)

Any help with how to get the console logs to show?

Answer (score 1):

It appears Safari 13.1 has left support for iOS 9 behind, I am having the same issue with an iPad on iOS 9.3.1 that worked just fine with Safari 13. I hope this is a temporary bug.

Edit: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60963057/safari-web-inspector-is-only-showing-sources-console-and-audit)