# How to recreate mobile css error on desktop view

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, firefox-developer-tools

I have very strange question. I have site http://www.printer1.ssk.pl/ and problem with search (right side). When I vist this side on computer or even on firefox with mobile view (720px x...) this search bar is display ok. But when I check this website on my phone the search bar is display wrong. I want to recreate this problem on computer, firefox where I can fix them. But now I can't recreate this problem. Anyone know why ?

Also I install switch agent to firefox. With no results.

Comment: Why do you need to recreate the problem on desktop? Are you aware that you can debug mobile webpages on the device? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794984/how-to-debug-web-sites-on-mobile-devices

Comment: Did you try the [Responsive Design Mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Responsive_Design_Mode) (Ctrl-Shift-M, or Cmd-Opt-M on OSX).

Comment: Also, in what way is the display wrong? Maybe you could post a screenshot of what you see.

Comment: Try RDM (Ctrl+Shift+M) and select a device from list, you will see the page get refresh and user-agent will be changed to selected device, then you can debug your code.