# How to inspect code on real mobile (Mobile debugging)

Tags: debugging, mobile, jquery-mobile, web-inspector, code-inspection

I want to inspect my code on mobile but there is no option on the mobile device to inspect code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to debug web sites on mobile devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794984/how-to-debug-web-sites-on-mobile-devices)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visit this URL to solve the issue and create mobile debuggingg
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging