# How can I troubleshoot HTML/CSS on my mobile phone running a chrome browser?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, mobile, google-chrome-devtools

I use Chrome Debugger on my PC to debug my web application, and it has a new handy feature where I can set the debuger to a mobile device, in this case Iphone 7.

Supposedly this allows you to emulate a mobile device.  However, despite doing this I am getting different results, that is, it is not emulating the iPhone 7 device accurately.

There is an SVG component completely missing in the mobile browser.  Very odd.

I have never troubleshot my web app on a mobile device, but need a means to do this.  I also need a means to report the debugger as not accurately emulating the mobile device.

I did some googling and found this [SO Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794984/how-to-debug-web-sites-on-mobile-devices), however it is about 10 years old.

Here is a screen shot of the emulator and the icon that is **actually missing on my mobile device**:

[image]

Comment: I'm a bit confused:  Your question title-- _"How can I troubleshoot HTML/CSS on my mobile phone running a chrome browser?""_-- makes it sound like you want to debug your site on an actual device, but the question body makes it sound as though you simply want a way to accurately emulate the site as if it was running on a device.  Which is it?

Comment: I want something that is accurate and works.  Currently using Desktop Chrome debugger does not accurately emulate the mobile browser.  Whatever works, either an emulator that is accurate or the actual device

Comment: If you have a Mac, you _might_ be able to get XCode (used for iOS development) and Android Studio (used for Android Development) and see if you could use their emulated devices and point them at localhost port on which you're running your web app.  Also, with Android devices, you _can_ actually plug them into a device and use the Chrome devtools to debug the page running on Chrome in the phone-- not sure if this works for iPhones, though.

Answer (score 1):

Those situations are tricky...you need to use a device emulator such as https://crossbrowsertesting.com/