# How to upload my website to a localserver for another user to see from his own computer

Tags: php, mysql, web

For example, I have a website made for my manager. He needs to view the website and interact with it easily. He needs to view to all the Policies of the Website that I have uploaded and interact it in order to make further changes to it using his own computer. How do you do this and how is it possible.

I am using XAMPP (localhost to view all my websites) How can the other user view my website without having to install XAMPP in his computer? Is it possible for MySQL to be shared with another computer ?

Comment: Ermm, host it online somewhere?

Comment: or you can simply [open access to XAMPP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524116/accessing-localhost-xampp-from-another-computer-over-lan-network-how-to).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of services providing what you ask. The services create a tunnel to your localhost in order to allow other people to access it.

Some examples:

- https://ngrok.com/
- http://localtunnel.me/
- http://proxylocal.com/
- http://www.ultrahook.com/
- https://forwardhq.com/

I've heard that if you’re just getting started, You should use ngrok. Client set up is the easiest and it offers the most features of any of the options and its completely free.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to solve your problem.

You can provide **access to your local machine**. Therefore you have to check your firewall settings and normally open port 80 or 8080. Then you have to decide:

- When the second person **is in the same local network**, you
  normally only have to share your local IP. To find out your local IP as a windows user, you have to open the command shell and type *ipconfig*. (Pay attention: in complex network structures this is not always the trick. Perhaps you have to contact your local admin.)
- When the second person is **not in the same network**, you can configure
  a portforwarding on your router. To share your public IP you could
  use an additional DYNDNS-Service ([dyndns](http://dyn.com/dns/)) or just spread the ip yourself ([whatismyip](http://www.whatismyip.com/)). I would **not recommend** that solution
  for a long time and you should only provide temporary access to a local service in your network.

You can also use a **tunnel** to offer a local service. For example:

- [localtunnel.me](http://localtunnel.me/)
- [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/)

Another solution would be to use a **public webhoster**. It's an affordable solution and you don't have to worry about any local issues. If you often want to offer your service or even run it 24/7, i would prefer this solution.

For experienced users there is also the possibility by bypassing the service with a **reverse ssh** portforwarding. For additional information i would recommend following blog-post: [toic.org - reverse-ssh-port-forwarding](http://toic.org/blog/2009/reverse-ssh-port-forwarding/).

Answer (score 2):

just download visual studio code and once you do then go to extensions and install live server so then once you are done coding your website or app the just hit the go live button.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply replace 127.0.0.1 or localhost with your IP address in the url ( assuming that you are both in the same office network ). e.g. replace `localhost/project/index.php` with `yourip/project/index.php`

if on windows just type `ipconfig` in your command prompt or try `ifconfig` on mac or linux to find out your ip.

Comment: It works for me however I take you point, it will only work if all the conditions are right.

Comment: I just opened Port 80 in Firewall and allowed all access what should I do now? Yes i am in an Office network.

Comment: find out your local IP address and try it out in your browser.