# Localhost Cross Browser Testing on Virtual Machine

Tags: php, localhost, virtual-machine

I have a PHP application running locally using MAMP Pro. I am in the process of conducting cross browser testing and I need to use IE. I have IE9 and IE10 setup as virtual machines (from `http://www.modern.ie/`) but I am unable to access localhost on these. Am I correct in thinking I need to find the IP address and access it that way or is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: Would you like to share your `MAMP` in LAN/WAN?

Comment: Yes preferably just LAN. On my mac I've setup a virtual host, http://example.dev, so the site would need to be accessible through this address or it would redirect.

Comment: Unless you run MAMP in all the VMs, it will not be localhost for the VMs that you're running IE in. You need to use the specific IP of the server VM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they are on virtual machines, then they are not on the same machine. They have their own network interfaces and their own IP addresses (including their own loopback interfaces).

You'll need to use either the IP address (or a hostname that maps on to it) facing the virtual machine on the virtual network or the LAN IP address (if the network is configured to allow that) instead of `localhost`.

`ifconfig` should tell you what ip addresses are bound to your Mac.

Comment: +1 good answer as always .. but hey its kind of schoolboy question :)

Answer (score 0):

search for .htosts in windows folder and put there your localhost and ip or try accesing the localhost machine by typing the routed ip or something like that

Answer (score 0):

I would like to check 
[stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524116/accessing-localhost-xampp-from-another-computer-%20over-lan-network-how-to) to share your server in LAN. Though, this answer based on `Windows`, Hope it will gather some knowledge to do this on `MAC`.

Open, `httpd.conf` file from `apache` conf folder and modify permission to access `MAMP` from virtual machine.

There are few consideration-

1. Allow your IP-Address by modifying `httpd.conf` to access from virtual machine
2. Give the `phpmyadmin` folder permission to access from virtual machine
3. Give the `Directory` permission to access from virtual machine