# Windows wamp phpmyadmin gets redirected

Tags: wamp

The wamp phpmyadmin on my localhost keeps getting redirected to the phpmyadmin of the live site instead. I can can access my localhost though. Only the phpmyadmin is wrong

I have no idea how to fix this. Anyone can help?

Comment: What url are you using to access phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Apache configuration [posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22112706/3367835)

If you tampered (changed) the hosts file you need to remove any of your own edits related to localhost, other than the defaults. If you don't know what that is or you did not change anything there, than it is not a hosts file issue and it is most probably the Apache configuration

phpmyadmin is configured to be accessible only from http:// localhost