# Public page in PHP (XAMPP)

Tags: php, xampp, local-network

I am having XAMPP installed on my system. I need to make a page public in such a way that people on the same network can access that page with a url like :

192.168.1.2/myPublicPage.php
Is there any way for doing this ?

Comment: htdocs folder is a public folder in LAN, htdocs /myPublicPage.php

Comment: yes my page is in that directory only and it runs fine on my system (aka localhost) but I want to run it on any system on IP ...do I have to change some config file for that (because it is not working by default)?

Answer (score 0):

right click on xamp icon in tray icons and make sure that is online (put online if not)
make sure that you are not using firewall to block your connectivity.

put files on your www folder , for example : myPublicPage.php
and access from other computers in your local area network by your xamp server ip and document name. for example 192.168.1.2/myPublicPage.php

Comment: this is not working by default, that is why I have posted it as a question brother.

Comment: make sure about firewall and antivirus blocking services and check xamp port. this link may be useful for you [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524116/accessing-localhost-xampp-from-another-computer-over-lan-network-how-to)

Comment: ok...is there any change to be done in httpd.conf file ..I googled and got confused regarding that file

Comment: most important part of httpd.conf is allow or deny access from other computers `<Directory "c:/xamp/www/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>` then restart all services and put online xamp. its recommended to make a backup before any edit at httpd.conf file for any rollback or restore