# How to access local WordPress installs from other machines on my network

Tags: wordpress, networking, xampp

I have XAMPP running fine on one machine and I have 2 WordPress installs running fine on that machine. I would like to be able to access and work on those WordPress installs on other machines on my network.

Right now, I have it set so that if I try to access those directories from another computer on the network, all I get is either the XAMPP splash screen, or a 404 error if I try to access specific folders.

I've researched this and researched this and I have found numerous posts about how to do this.... but only in bits and pieces.

Does anyone know of a step by step, start to finish,  guide of how to do this? In layman's terms?

Remote (from another network) would be great too. But I'll cross that bridge once I figure this out.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: what you want with access? edit posts, pages or different?

Comment: Complete access to develop the site. Including, posts, pages, wp dashboard, css...

I can access the files via my network and shared folders, I just can't view the site in a browser or edit anything from inside the wordpress dashboard from other machines on the network.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest rather than shared folders you use an FTP client / server - I use Filezilla server and client for my local sandbox testing server. This will give you additional info like file and folder groups and permissions.

Got to ask the question what OS? have you opened port 80 on the server machine?

Things like this can also occur on Linux if the folders and files do not have the correct groups for access and or permissions.

chown -R apache:apache /var/www/html

the above if on linux will assign all the folders and files to be accessed by the apache process. not having the correct groups assigned can give you 404 when you know the files are actually there.

also check the file and folder permissions,

different files and directories have permissions that specify who and what can read, write, modify and access them - this wordpress page gives a good overview of permissions
http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions

edit p.s. to access then from other networks all you will have to do is forward ports from your router to your internal server then your ftp and www services will be accessable from the outside world. I would suggest using a .htpass htaccess password to protect your services at this point.

Comment: Hmmmm..... Some of this makes sense to me... some seems over my head. 

The host computer is running Windows 7 and the other machine I would like to access the sites with is running Windows 8.1

Gonna have to re-read what you wrote and see if I can figure it out... I know it sounds bad (and ignorant) but I need a 1.)Click here, 2.)Type this, 3.)Save that.... type of instructions. 

Part of the trouble I'm having trying to figure out what to do is, from my research... people say, You should add "this code" and it'll work. But they don't say where to add "this code". Does that make sense?<br />

Comment: I do use FileZilla regularly but I've never used it to try to connect to a machine on my local network.

Comment: And... I understand what your trying to say by opening port 80 on my machine, but have no idea how to actually do that.

Comment: Hi @CaptClay - I have just checked and I dont think the file permissions aspect or groups aspects of my answer apply to you (its linux stuff).

Comment: I wonder if you just need to turn off the firewall on the windows 7 machine to test, then if it works turn the firewall back on and create a rule to allow traffic via port 80 on the server (again done in windows firewall). perhaps also turn off your antivirus when doing the intial checks - but ofc turn the back on again...but if you do get a splashscreen then it rules this out really because the data does flow. Sorry, looks like my ave is redundant for you >.<

Comment: Firewall or the httpd.conf is only listening on 127.0.0.1 - explanations here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524116/accessing-localhost-xampp-from-another-computer-over-lan-network-how-to