# How to access XAMPP server from another device?

Tags: php, networking, xampp, localhost, server

I'm running an Apache server using XAMPP and want to access files from another device on the same Wifi network.

I tried using the IPv4 address of my computer but wasn't able to connect from another laptop. 
I also tried disabling the firewall and that did not work either

I'd like to access it from devices on a separate network after this.

I'm working with Google Cloud Messaging on Android, and it requires sending information as well as reading information which requires server access.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524116/accessing-localhost-xampp-from-another-computer-over-lan-network-how-to

Comment: I followed what that link said before I posted this question.

Comment: same question http://stackoverflow.com/a/22112706/5043552 but not the accepted answer will show you apache configuration for allowing different IPs

Comment: Just tried what most posters there said. Still doesn't work.

Comment: Ah! Got it working. Such a silly mistake I made. I was using the Ethernet Adapter Virtualbox IPv4 address presented in ipconfig, when I really needed to use the Wireless LAN adapter Wifi-Fi. Doing netstat -a showed my the local IP address of my computer where I caught the error. Works perfectly now :) Now I'm just wondering how I can access it from devices not on the network, and do it safely?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should check http://localtunnel.me. Hope this works for you!

Comment: Seems cool, is this on Windows too? That looks like a unix command. I'll check out.I

Comment: To anyone reading this in the future wondering, I use ngrok for both my mac and my windows machine and it works perfectly. It assigns you a public URL to access the server externally or internally. Works on Linux as well.

Comment: localtunnel not avail for my mac or windows. but I made a stupid mistake and using the correct lan IP worked. Alternatively, ngrok works too.