# Connect XAMPP website over WiFi network from Android Phone/Other connected device

Tags: android, networking, xampp, localhost, wifi

I am trying to connect to a local website from my PC running XAMPP (IP address made static at 192.168.1.100). I tried many workarounds ([one of them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524116/accessing-localhost-xampp-from-another-computer-over-lan-network-how-to)) given on the internet but everytime I try to connect to my website from my Android Device (connected to same wifi network) using `http://192.168.1.100/mywebsite` it gets redirected to `http://localhost/mywebsite` which I suppose is correct if I use it on the same PC running XAMPP but not for the Android device. I even tried to name the IP in `hosts` on my PC (running Windows 7 Ultimate). But that didn't worked as well. Tried it to call using `http://mypcname/mywebsite` which ofcourse gave the same result as above.

Am I required to set-up some Forwarding on my WiFi Router, if so, how can I do that? Or there is something else I am missing?

Comment: That ip address should work. Who is redirecting?  Where do you see 'http:\\locathost' ? About which app/browser are you talking? Has this anything to do with coding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!!!

The problem was actually with the Subnet. [Here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/2658ad89-3d3b-494b-8653-dca1be0a35d1/how-to-open-all-tcpudp-ports-to-a-subnet?forum=winservergen) are the steps that actually worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You should type `ipconfig` in the Commands Prompt, and look up the IPv4 address of your Wireless adapter. Use it to connect to localhost. I usually do it like this and it works fine.

Comment: I've already mentioned that the IP address has been set to `192.168.1.100` i.e. static. So, I don't think this would help me to achieve what I want.