# I'm trying to share a web app I created with PHP,HTML,CSS and JS

Tags: xampp

I created an app with the above mention technologies, and I hosted it on local server of XAMPP, now I'm trying to figure out how to share this checkout system app with 4 other coworkers, so they can easily access the app on their on PC and checkout equipment to other customers when I'm not around.

We are all on the same network, wired LAN.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: if you open your xampp to public, they should be able to access it if they use your lan IP adress.

Comment: Thanks Nicolas for your quick response, I'm pretty new to development, but how do I open xampp to public, do I just go into the folder properties ?

Comment: Well either you create some package for them to install, easiest would be a docker container, or you install it on some system _always_ available in your network.

Comment: You should refer to this question, it gives plenty of information on the subject http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524116/accessing-localhost-xampp-from-another-computer-over-lan-network-how-to

Comment: I had install xampp on my own workstation, which is always available, never shut show or go to sleep. I leave it powered on.

Answer (score 0):

This solved what I'm basically trying to do, because all computers where on the same network.

I did IPCONFIG, in cmd to view my IPV4, then went to a different PC, knowing my IP4V, I went into a browser on a different PC and did

http://192.168.XX.XXX/SomeFolderInSidehtcdoc/myappfolder/index.php

and behold it opened, I entered data into it, and checked out my database and same data were available.