# How do I access my localhost WordPress website on XAMPP from another computer?

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, xampp

I have a localhost WordPress website on XAMPP, and I would like to access it from another computer. How do I do it?

So far I've tried the following actions with no success:

1. Go to Admin Panel > Settings > General and replace localhost with your ip-address for WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL).
2. edit httpd.conf file in notepad
   Search for Listen 80
   Above line would read like- #Listen 0.0.0.0:80 / 12.34.56.78:80
   Change the IP address and replace it with the static IP
   Save the httpd.conf file ensuring that the server is pointed to #Listen 192.168.1.193:80
3. In the application root config.php (db connection) replace localhost with IP address of the server
4. Add in httpd.conf: 
   Allow from all
5. changed the structure of .htaccess
6. Add in Directory in httpd-xampp.conf:
   Require local

Comment: Sounds like you arent allowing connections through your firewall. I'd start by checking there is an outbound/inbound rule that allows the page to be accessed remotely. Standard wordpress setup wouldnt require any additional changes to allow a remote connection

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing localhost (xampp) from another computer over LAN network - how to?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524116/accessing-localhost-xampp-from-another-computer-over-lan-network-how-to)

Comment: I've added an inbound rule on port 80, and still nothing.

Answer (score 1):

So, i found that actually you don't have to do much, all you have to do is go to the Wordpress Admin panel, then General Settings, after that you have to change the **WordPress Address (URL)** and the **Site Address (URL)**:

To be instead of `http://localhost/wordpress_folder_name` to `http://your_ip/wordpress_folder_name`

[As shown is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UF9AE.png)

This is because when you try to access the localhost from another computer, the project will try to load all the `wp-content` from an unexisting `localhost` of the device your trying to access with and not from the device that is running XAMPP.