# Laravel - How to share application to another stations

Tags: php, laravel, server, xampp

I developed an application with laravel and i put it in a local server and i need that other computer access it.

I think that have 2 solutions:

**First:** Access to laravel server (port 8000)
**Second:** Put the project in xampp

What is the best solution?

With the first option i can't access and with xampp it doesn't access well to routes and doesn't load the css and js files.
If i access to root folder it list the project folders and i have to go to public folder but doesn't load stylesheet files.

How can i do that?

**UPDATE:**

I did this steps and this not work yet.

In `httpd.conf` enable this line `Include /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`

Next i add a host in in hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1 arquivo.localhost
```

Next i'm going to `httpd-vhosts.conf` and add this:

```
<VirtualHost *:8888>
  DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/arquivo/public"
  ServerAdmin arquivo.localhost
  <Directory "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/arquivo/public">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Next i restart the apache and when i try to access to `http://arquivo.localhost` this give me `This site can’t be reached`

What i'm doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: to browse the app from other computer the computer should be in network. are they?? Second is the running perfect from localhsot.

Comment: yes, the computers are in same network and in localhost works fine. @MASIDDIQUI

Answer (score 0):

create virtualhost under xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhost.conf
like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost.com
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/laravel/public"
ServerName laravel.localhost
ErrorLog "logs/laravel-error.log"
CustomLog "logs/laravel-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

and access with http://laravel.localhost/

Comment: don't forgot to restart apache after creating virtualhost

Comment: I do this and i stop and start the apache.
When i put laravel.app in browser i have serve not found error.
And if i go to project folder ihave the public folder but if in the browser i put localhost:81/laravel this list all project folder but the public folder doesn't show. @D.Pachauri

Comment: you cant access laravel app forlder directly. if you have created virtualhost  exactly like above then http://laravel.localhost/ should run.

Comment: but i cannot change the server name? In my case i put laravel.app but not because folder app @D.Pachauri

Comment: now tell me not found. The request resource is not found. @D.Pachauri

Comment: i'm using port 81 but set it in virtual host. @D.Pachauri

Answer (score 0):

If its working fine on your localhost, other person can access your site using your `Ip` address, provided you both are on same local network.

For more you can see this reference : [Accessing localhost (xampp) from another computer over LAN network - how to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524116/accessing-localhost-xampp-from-another-computer-over-lan-network-how-to)