# access xampp server from other PC over LAN

Tags: php, apache

I just downloaded the latest XAMPP version installed it on my new PC.
however I cannot access the local webserver via browser(Google Chrome) from another PC on my LAN.

I allowed MySQL and Apache through my Firewall.
setup a static IP on my server PC. (192.168.1.130)
I also changed the configuration of httpd.conf file

**from**

```
<Directory />
   AllowOverride none
   Require all denied
</Directory>
```

**to**

```
<Directory />
   AllowOverride All
   Require all denied
</Directory>
```

then I restarted apache.. still cannot access it via IP or Computer name.

Comment: How are you trying to access it, what is the URL? Which port number are you using?

Comment: I'm trying to access it on a browser by typing the IP address of the local server.   `http://192.168.1.130` or `http://ComputerName`

Comment: Check the apache config files for the port number you are listening on. Default when using the browser would be 80.

Comment: it is listening on port 80

Comment: Do you get an 404 or 500 error, or does it not connect at all?

Comment: I didn't get any errors.. it does not connect at all.. but if I ping (via CMD) the server IP from the other PC I did get a reply from the server.. I can also access the shared folders on the server

Comment: Did you set the proper network settings for LAN?

Comment: @hungrykoala yes I did..

Comment: @KimCarlo try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524116/accessing-localhost-xampp-from-another-computer-over-lan-network-how-to) from what I remember i needed to do something like allow all in config for this to work

Comment: @hungrykoala I already read that post.. I tried all the suggestions but nothing worked for me.. still searching for answers..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay so after tons of searches, I finally found an answer, here's what I did..

Go into the Windows Firewall settings and click the "Advanced" button, and in the next dialog click "Inbound Rules" - click "New Rule"

1. In the rule type window, choose Port
2. In the program window, leave All Programs selected
3. In protocols and ports, leave protocol as TCP, and Local Ports should be "Specific Ports", enter 80,443
4. In the scope window, don't enter any specific ip addresses
5. In the action window, Allow the Connection
6. In the profile window, leave them all ticked
7. And finally, in the name, call it something useful, like HTTP_ports

credits to this [link](https://superuser.com/questions/569227/xampp-is-not-accessible-from-other-computer-through-lan-when-firewall-is-enable)

Comment: Worked brilliantly! Incidentally, Step 4 is missing on my computer.  I did not get the choice to provide an ip address scope.