# Can't access some localhost applications from another computer

Tags: php, xampp, localhost

I'm using xampp to run web applications on local server.

Now, I'm testing two applications:

http://localhost/ontrack/

http://localhost/perfex/

I tried to access both of them from another device (tried mobile and other laptops connected to the same wifi.

my IP address: 192.168.137.1

http://localhost/ontrack/

[First Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNxlf.jpg)

(worked fine)

http://localhost/perfex/

[Second Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npkkF.jpg)

The IP address is reverted to localhost and not working.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing localhost (xampp) from another computer over LAN network - how to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524116/accessing-localhost-xampp-from-another-computer-over-lan-network-how-to) [access xampp server from other PC over LAN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43844434/4903314)

Comment: I've found the problem, it's related to perfex crm configuration itself. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @MohamedShamoon If you post the solution here (answer your own question), it could help someone in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do is to open `app-config.php` and change this line to whatever I wanted.

```
define('APP_BASE_URL', 'http://localhost/crm292/');
```