# xampp installed on Mac not accessible via localhost, only local ip

Tags: php, xampp, localhost

After intalling Xampp on my Mac.
The address is http://192.168.64.2/dashboard
how can I make it to be accessible via localhost or 127.0.0.1 ?

Comment: Maybe read through this question/answers to find some help: 
https://stackoverflow.com/q/5524116/5039312

Comment: uninstalling teamviewer solved my problem

Answer (score 16):

You most likely installed the application that sets up a virtual machine. Revisit the download page and select the application without 'vm' at the end

here: https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html

Comment: Thanks.  Poor UI on their Web site.

Answer (score 4):

Like Ab Ned said, you've probably installed the VM version. I guess that's a good thing because it might save your from unwanted side-effects. So, if you want to stick with it, just activate the port forwarding:

[image]

There's also a little walkthrough at https://www.apachefriends.org/faq_stackman.html.

Comment: Enable the port forwarding and go to  http://localhost:8080. This worked for me.