# Accessing a local website from another computer inside the local network using XAMPP through MySQL & phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

Ok, so here is the scenario:

I have computer A inside my local network.I added a new website, let's say http://localhost:81/hesk/admin/admin_main.php using XAMPP through Mysql & phpMyAdmin.
So, in a browser running in computer A, if I type http://localhost:81/hesk/admin/admin_main.php in the address bar and hit Enter, everything works fine. I can access the website.

Now I wanted to access this website from other local computers, say, computer B , not from the outside world, but from inside the same local network.
Computer A's IP is 192.168.1.59, and http://localhost:81/hesk/admin/admin_main.php is running on port 81.
Edit :- i am using simple d-link router where i have given static ip to my hosted PC & all others are in DHCP automatic Get an ip mode.

Comment: So you can do like: `http://192.168.1.59:81/hesk/admin/admin_main.php`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing localhost (xampp) from another computer over LAN network - how to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524116/accessing-localhost-xampp-from-another-computer-over-lan-network-how-to)

Comment: http://192.168.1.59:81/hesk/admin/admin_main.php = using this browser says - This site can't be reached.Localhost refused to connect .

Answer (score 1):

Use the **ip address** of the system which has the php code, instead of `localhost` in the same url.

For your code you should use: [192.168.1.59:81/hesk/admin/admin_main.php](http://192.168.1.59:81/hesk/admin/admin_main.php)

**Note:** you should have your `apache` and `mysql` started in your xampp control panel on your server computer(A)