# Allow users across local network to access the web page?

Tags: php, html, web, server

I have created a login page(HTML form page) that asks for username and password and then sends it to ABC.php and if correct, it redirects them to another site. I have installed `xampp` server for it.

But now I want that this feature should extend to other users connected to my pc via some WiFi or Ethernet cable i.e. they should able to access login page, enter their credentials and access the other site.

Comment: Please share your code so we can better help you out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing localhost (xampp) from another computer over LAN network - how to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524116/accessing-localhost-xampp-from-another-computer-over-lan-network-how-to)

Answer (score 0):

Share your ip address instead of localhost:portno/project/path/index.php
This will give the access of the instance of your project if you are working in same LAN connection.
So, they will be accessing your localhost as http://192.168.xxxx.xxxx:80/Project/index.php.
And use their own credentials to login.

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Check Localtunnel, it'll provide an API connected to your pc local port, just with one line in terminal.

```
>npm install localtunnel -g
```

If you don't have node.js install it from official executable.

Once localtunnel installed just type:

```
>lt --port 80 --subdomain what-you-want
```

This command permit to all people, outside your LAN too, to connect to: what-you-want.localtunnel.me