# How to use a npm package

Tags: javascript, php, npm, popup, npm-scripts

I have installed this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/selection-popup
I was wondering how do I use it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing localhost (xampp) from another computer over LAN network - how to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524116/accessing-localhost-xampp-from-another-computer-over-lan-network-how-to)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting. You are not asking a programming question here. You might get an answer on [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/) or [superuser](https://superuser.com/). Friendly advice: From what I understand of your question, I get the impression you are lacking a lot of basic knowledge you will need to understand the answers people will give you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting your site viewable by remote users (people on the internet) isn't as simple as setting up an apache server.  You'll also need a domain name (in your example, mydigitalplanner.net) from a domain registrar like [GoDaddy](https://godaddy.com).  Once you have that, you'll need to [add an A-record](https://ca.godaddy.com/help/add-an-a-record-19238) and point it to the [external IP address](https://www.whatsmyip.org/) for your server.

So far so good.  You'll also want to make sure your computer has a [static IP address](https://www.pcmag.com/how-to/how-to-set-up-a-static-ip-address) (one that doesn't change every so often).  Finally, you'll want to make sure that port 80 is open on your server box (and in your router's configuration, you'll need to forward port 80 to your server's IP).