# creating database without coding

Tags: database

I want to create a localhost database that allows me to enters data easily without coding.

For example, I want to create books database that stores: title, price, and publisher.And I want to enter data manually just like we are entering it in Excel. I mean without coding.

do you have any suggestions?

Comment: if you using mysql, try mysql workbench...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install [Xampp](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html)

**Xampp** is one of my favorite ***Apache Local Server***

Then, activate the sql, and enter to **MyPhpAdmin**

---

If you want Client Database, you can comfortably install [MySql Workbench](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/)

This's localhost ***Cient database UI*** and much better if you want to create only database work.

Comment: Cool! It seems myPhpAdmin is a good choice. But what about if I want to access the database from many computers is it possible?

Comment: Hi, @Nora. In this case, I think this person may answer this question better than me [Accessing localhost (xampp) from another computer over LAN network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524116/accessing-localhost-xampp-from-another-computer-over-lan-network-how-to)

Answer (score 0):

Install [phpMyAdmin](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/)

Start it in server mode

create a table with all the columns -  title, price, and publisher

You are good to go