# Access Virtual Host from different devices in LAN

Tags: xampp, wamp, virtualhost, lan

I have set up a Virtual Host on my local machine with XAMPP and everything works just fine. My vh name is mysite.local and I can access it just fine through LAN too, using the IP Address of my computer which is http://192.168.1.112/mysite.local
My question is: Is there any way to access the same local domain (mysite.local) through my phone without using the IP Address, so just http://mysite.local?
I have made tons of research but couldnt find a solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe making a hostname for the IP within the router.
And then place your index file in \xampp\htdocs (so XAMPP will put it under your IP).

not my area of knowledge.

info about hostnames:
https://homenetworkguy.com/how-to/use-custom-domain-name-in-internal-network/

Comment: Thanks for your input. I already have a hostname binded to the ip address which is mysite.local. It all works great with XAMPP but I cannot access this name from my mobile phone in the same network.

Comment: Hi, how is it going found a solution? Where you able to load the site through the ip? "there is a chance that there is a firewall running on your computer, or the httpd.conf is only listening on 127.0.0.1" - source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5524127/14579429

Comment: I am able to load the website through the IP address of the computer im hosting the files, however I was looking for a solution to use a LAN domain name and nothing found yet. I mean, a domain name in LAN that should work on all devices including smart phones. Ex. mysite.test