# Hosting database in Xampp (in separate fixed port)

Tags: apache, xampp, ip, shared-hosting, ipconfig

I have successfully hosted database with xampp

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48990347/15493370

This is the link which I followed. Now It works fine but there is one problem. I want the database to be hosted in `192.168.100.2:8080` forever. How can I do that?

Suppose my current Ip is `192.168.100.59`.

On using `ipconfig`

```
Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.100.59
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : fe80::1%12
                                       192.168.100.1
```

I have not included ipv6 as it is not used anywhere.

I tried using IP `192.168.100.2` in the `httpd.conf` file. It still listens to `192.168.100.59` not what I want.

So my question is How can I make it host to fixed private Ip in LAN at any time
Or
Will it change overtime
If so how can I solve this problem. (I am not connecting different networks just single network )

Answer (score 0):

You have to statically set your ip address so when your pc/server restarts/reboots it doesn't change its ip.
Alternatively you can create a static lease on dhcp server based on your server's mac address and always assign the same ip to that mac.