# React Native Php server.json https://192.168.2.7/project/index.php

Tags: php, react-native, json-server

How to use public ip address and access by different devices and network

Public ip address
React Native PHP

I use ngrok and it works but my own public ip address is not how to handle this kind of connection any comments will helps

Comment: How do you serve your PHP server? Is it on local server? xampp/wamp? docker nginx/apache?

Comment: xampp nginx/apache

Comment: I am going to assume this in hosted in your local machine windows with xampp.

Comment: xampp uses apache not nginx.. at least the default is

Comment: Did you check other answers in the internet? blogs? Start with this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48990347